# How to track a button in GTM when you don't have click ID or click class as variables?

Tags: css, google-tag-manager, elementor

I figured out the part I can use click element to track the button but , But i guess it's not as straight forward as using click ID or Click Class, I tried adding click ID but as I'm not using Elementor pro, i had my restrictions. Is there a way around or if I can only use click element to track can someone help me out? [this is my website](https://www.keralataxis.com/) I'm attaching the codes of the buttons that I want to track[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M05au.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drgkh.png)

I tried to bring click ID to my buttons by pasting the below given code in my theme but it didn't work as I couldn't add attribute to my buttons because I'm not using elementor pro

`/** Button Fix for Tag Manager (For Click Id triggering) **/

.elementor-button-content-wrapper{pointer-events: none;}

.elementor-button span{pointer-events: none;}`

Comment: In the case I guess you want to track the `<a>` element. Is there any special requirement for not tracking it?

Comment: I don't know which element to choose for tracking, but if  you are asking me to track the URL I don't want that as I have lot of other buttons in my website that lead to the same URL.  Correct me if I'm wrong my coding skills are very minimal. If you help me select an unique element to track that would be great.
Thank you responding

Comment: I have <i>(::before) and <span> in side my <a> tag , how should I go about it? @darrelltw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment you provided.

I will suggest this way :

Looks like you want to track the `<a>` element only if the element contain certain  element right?

In this case.

1. Set up the trigger for `Link Click`
2. Check if you select the `Click Element` in your built-in variable
3. Set up a variable with the type `custom javascript` and paste this code and naming it property. I would name `CJS - check element has fa-search`.

```
function(){
    var clickedElement = {{Click Element}};

    // Let's say you want to check if <a> element contains i.fa-list-alt. You can change the selector to you want.
    var childElement = clickedElement.querySelector('i.fa-list-alt');
    
    if (childElement) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

4. Create another trigger. Select the `Link Click` for the  with another condition is {{CJS - check element has fa-search}} equals to true.

---

You can think through this idea is good for you or not.